# Bolzano’s Intermediate Value Theorem for a function of 2 closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We have Bolzano’s Intermediate Value Theorem (Source: Introduction to Real Analysis by Robert Bartle & Donald Sherbert):

Let $I$ be an interval and let $f: I\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $I$.
If $a,b \in I$ and if $k \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(a)< k < f (b)$,
then there exists a point $c \in I$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f (c) = k$.

My understanding of the theorem got me in contradiction; Suppose $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, $I = [a, b] \cup [c, d]$, where $b < c$, and $f: I\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous on $I$.

Now we let $e \in \mathbb{R}$,  $b < e < c$, i.e. $e \notin I$.
So there exist some interval $[j, k]$ between $f(b)$ and $f(c)$, such that $[j, k] \not\subset f(x)$

Example:
$f(x) = x$, $f:[1, 2] \cup [4, 5] \to \mathbb{R}$. But there exists $k=3$, where $2 < k < 4$.
But there is no $f(x) = 3$.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: $[a, b] ∪ [c, d]$ is not an interval.

Comment: In fact, IVP does not hold on any set of real numbers which is not an interval!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think $[a,b]\cup[c,d]$ is an interval. Remember that only the union of intervals with a common point is an interval. So that's why your counter-example cannot hold.